# Deploy node js application with express framework on production mode

Tags: node.js, express, pm2

How to deploy node js application with express framework with production environment variable with pm2 and generate startup script for reboot with same production environment variable.

I have used this so far

```
pm2 start hello.js
pm2 startup systemd 
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup 
systemd -u sammy --hp /home/sammy
```

It starts the application on reboot but in development mode

Answer (score 0):

To start a Node.js app in production mode, you'd need to set the `NODE_ENV` like so:

```
NODE_ENV=production # updates from 'development' to 'production'
pm2 start hello.js
pm2 startup systemd 
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup 
systemd -u sammy --hp /home/sammy
```

Comment: but will environment reset back to development on reboot

Comment: It might, if you want it to be always production, you need to add it to your server environment variables

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: Are you using AWS or DigitalOcean?